# core_config_data table keeps on reloading in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, core-config-data, wamp

To make a change, I opened **core_config_data** table in Magento 2 DB, but it keeps on reloading even after I disabled the new module.

What should I do ?

Now all the tables have the same issue.

[image]

Comment: check with other database still the issue occurring then it's phpmyadmin issue if not then post your sql query which is shown in png file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to solve the above problem:-

1.) Open that table directly in mysql console and check if it opens normally, if it open correctly then the issue is with your phpmyadmin

2.) What is the configuration of your server, can it handle many databases on it. If server configuration is low and there are too many databases, remove the junk and unused databases after taking there backup.

3.) Check if any other background resources are not consuming server resources due to which your SQL query is taking time to load.

Comment: Issue was with phpmyadmin working in internet explorer